# So, I am writing a program based on writing and saving to a file, how can I code it so that it does not ignore spaces

Tags: c++

Heyo, So I coded a program that takes name, buying price, selling price and calculates Profit, it then organizes everything in a tabular format and writes it into a file, I wanted the program, after writing , to read back everything in the file to display the contents... but it seems that it skips spaces. Any way to get it to not skip those spaces? Heres the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int itemlist=0;
string x;
int randocount=0;
int c=0;
int r = 0;



int itemlistdec()
{
cout<<"How many items would you like to input?";
cin>>itemlist;  

try 
{
    if (itemlist<1)
    throw itemlist;
    else 
    return itemlist;
}

catch (const int caughtlist)
{
    cout<<"You cannot type less than 1 item ";
    cout<<"\n";
    itemlistdec();
}
}


int main() {


itemlistdec();
string item[4][itemlist];//declares item and that columns equal to itemlist whose content is declared right above

    for (int c=0;c<itemlist;c++)
    {

        for (int r=0;r<3;r++) //DETERMINES WHERE EACH RECORD GOES
        {
        if (r==0)
        {

        cout<<"Please enter the name of the item ";
        }

        if (r==1)
        {
            cout<<"Please input the buying price\n";
        }

        if (r==2)
        {
            cout<<"Please input the selling price\n";
        }

            cin>>item[r][c];

        }
    }

    int calc[3][itemlist];//declaring calc and itemlist

    for (int r = 0;r<itemlist;r++)
    {
        istringstream(item[1][r])>>calc[0][r]; //TAKES BUYING PRICE INTO INT ARRAY FOR CALCULATION

    }

    for (int r = 0;r<itemlist;r++)
    {
        istringstream(item[2][r])>>calc[1][r]; //TAKES SELLING PRICE INTO INT ARRAY FOR CALCULATION

    }

    for (int fart = 0;fart<itemlist;fart++)
    {
        calc[2][fart] = calc[1][fart] - calc[0][fart]; //REPEATS CALCULATION FOR PROFIT UNTIL ITEMLIST IS REACHED
    }


    for (int r = 0;r<itemlist;r++)
    {

    stringstream ss;
    ss<<calc[2][r]; //CONVERTS BOTH PROFIT VALUES INTO STRINGS
    item[3][r] = ss.str();

    }

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("C:\\Users\\ENVY 14\\Documents\\Plankarraywritten.txt");


    myfile<<"______________________________________________\n"; //DISPLAYS OUTPUT IN TABLE FORM
    myfile<<"Item\t\tBuying Price\t\tSelling Price\t\tProfit\n";

        for (int c=0;c<itemlist;c++)
    {


        for (int r=0;r<4;r++)
        { 
            myfile<<item[r][c]<<"\t\t";
            if (r==1)
            {
                myfile<<"\t";
            }
            if (r==2)
            {
                myfile<<"\t";
            }
            if (r==3)
            {
                myfile<<"\n";
            }
            randocount++;
        }
    }

myfile.close();

ifstream myifile;
myifile.open ("C:\\Users\\ENVY 14\\Documents\\Plankarraywritten.txt");

for (int read=0;read<randocount;read++)
{

 myifile>> x;
 cout<<x;
}
    myifile.close();




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your code, Your code does not even compile. **itemlist** must have a constant value to initialize **item** array. Use a vector or some STL container to store your variables of the item array.

And then use **[getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)** to read line by line from the file.

Comment: DEV C++ Allows for variable length arrays mate and thank you for the getline command :D Works wonderfully

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code is not even working since you cannot initialize an array like that. As your compiler will probably tell you, itemlist has to be a constant value. Fix that with some STL container like a vector or allocate the array on the heap. Also please remove that unnecessary exception handling:

```
try 
{
    if (itemlist<1)
    throw itemlist;
    else 
    return itemlist;
}

catch (const int caughtlist)
{
    cout<<"You cannot type less than 1 item ";
    cout<<"\n";
    itemlistdec();
}
```

A simple if statement is enough...

You cannot post some really basic code here that doesn't even compile.

(Also naming a variable 'fart' is questionable, grow up)

Comment: lol :D I really enjoyed reading but wanted to know why is it questionable if it certainly describes what he intends to

Comment: Yes true :-) I think it's pretty funny how Deadlock wrote the exact same stuff that has already been mentioned in my answer and in the comment of Maksim Solovjov.

Comment: DEV C++ Allows for variable length arrays mate so it does compile perfectly and performs its intended functions. I am a freshman and I kind of use this particular program to practice new techniques, code and the like. :D Last lesson at the time was exception handling. Also next time, please answer the question.

Comment: @YourfavOreo The thing is, beginner questions like yours don't belong to stackoverflow. You could have easily found that out by using google or any other search engine...

Comment: I have gotten loads of help from guys on stack overflow , whether by posting a question or a private messages. If your so bothered by me asking a beginner question... then press that red X on the top right mate... I love stackoverflow for the quick responses I get from the community. Unlike most people , I wasn't blessed with hours to do research and practice... I have to make due with what I can.